# Error 1054 from After-Insert Trigger

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pull a trigger to insert data from the one table to another. The main table receives it's data from an web interface which a user types in then when the submits the form it must send that data to the main table and also the a table i named backup.

I am using a after-insert trigger:

```
BEGIN
Insert INTO backup (MembershipNo, MembershipStartDate, MembershipExpiryDate, MembershipType ) //backup table that must get it's information from the clients table

VALUES ( //Data from the main table called clients
Membership_No, 
Membership_StartDate,
Membership_Type,
Membersship_ExpiryDate
);

END
```

When i try to insert data from the interface it throws this error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Membership_No' in 'field list'

I checked all my column in my php file they in place, also in my database, all the relevant columns are mentioned. I can't seem  to find what problem really us with the particular column. Please help.

Comment: The error says `Membership_No` but the column used in the trigger is `MembershipNo`

Comment: Prefix the values fields with new.

Comment: It worked thank you Salmon.